# ISNULL / IFNULL - MS Access vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have an MS Access application with a MySQL backend.  I'm trying to filter on a column that contains nulls.  I've tried to filter using:

```
isnull(fieldname,0)<>'Rejected'
```

but it doesn't return any records (which it should).  This criteria works in PHPMyAdmin, but not in Access. I get 'wrong number of arguments' for isnull and 'undefined function' for ifnull.

Comment: You could start with the manual: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/isnull-function-HA001228867.aspx   isnull() has only one argument, and PURELY tests for nullity. it has no "if value is null return something else" functionality.

Comment: Are you meaning to use [IIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx)?

Comment: Are you using a pass through query or is the query being processed by Access/the connection provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
(fieldname <> 'Rejected' or fieldname is null)
```

This will work in both databases and is standard SQL.  (Except that Access prefers double quotes for strings rather than single quotes.)